# Illegal Video Downloading Detection

Tags: php, html, flash, video, video-streaming

If a website has video streaming like youtube, is it possible to detect those that download illegally through video grabber applications? I assume such downloads would leave traceable marks or something to track down culprits, or maybe detect beforehand if someone is attempting to download video to log account details (and IP?) for future apprehension?

Why am I asking this? To cut the long story short, I'm in law school and I would need info regarding this for research case. Thanks. Hope this is the proper site to ask such question.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good question for StackOverflow but I wouldn't make the links public, protect the application at a user level.

Comment: There won't necessarily be any marks you can detect, if - for example - the downloader lets the original application do the download and just captures the stream after it has been fetched normally.

Comment: When you say after it is fetched normally, does it in a way mean it is stored locally in the computer? That has something to do with buffing - I believe that's what it is called, right? Then it is sadly, untraceable, yes?

Comment: it's "traceable" as in you can see who's downloading it to WATCH it, but there's no way to determine if someone is actually saving the data/video.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, yes and no.
You see, when you try to fetch ANYTHING from the internet, it is 'downloaded' to your computer. This usually goes to the browser's local storage system, so even when you are viewing it on youtube, it first downloads to your PC.

Now during this download, a download manager comes and listens to whatever youtube gave to the browser and makes a copy of it. Kinda like intercepting a letter, making a copy but not modifying the original letter in any way.

Its not usually possible to trace these guys down, but you can for example trace them by their IP. If they're using a personal downloader then this wont work, but a website for example will download from its own set of IPs, which you can blacklist.

SImilarly, website downloaders usually wont give you the data for something called the 'user-agent', so you could theoretically white-list user agents, at the cost of throwing out many browsers aswell.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Upvoted. But I got lost on the "it's not usually traceable but" part. Edit: oops it seems i can't upvote just yet.